# Mapping <kEnter> in Vim on Windows

Tags: vim

I am finding that I cannot map the keypad-Enter key differently from the standard Enter key. I only observe this in Windows (XP and 7), both console and GUI versions of Vim 7.3.540, with no plugins.

To demonstrate this, I tried the following maps:

- `nnoremap <kEnter> :echo "kEnter"<CR>` -- this is not triggered by Enter or keypad-Enter
- `nnoremap <Enter> :echo "Enter"<CR>` -- this is triggered by both Enter and keypad-Enter

So, is it possible to map `<Enter>` and `<kEnter>` to do different things in Windows, or are my attempts futile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. Seems to be working fine on Linux.
On Windows, the keypad enter key doesn't have a separate virtual key code ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but the two keys can be differentiated using the scan code. Vim probably doesn't do this.

I'm looking at this Autohotkey script that I made ([screenkey.ahk](https://github.com/mihaifm/screenkey.ahk)) and I can see that it can tell apart Enter from NumpadEnter.

So I can only speculate that this is Vim bug.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will take a look at the Vim source code to figure out what it's doing, but I may be out of my depth...